# Backbone js prevent url hash change when back/forward

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

I am working on a very basic SPA using Backbone.js. My app has few routes. Among them there are 2 that give me issues: the index route ("/#index") and menu route ("/#mainmenu").

A simple workflow in my app is as follows: the user fills a form -> clicks to login -> trigger ajax request -> if login successful go to "/#mainmenu" route. if login failed, remain on "/#index" route.
On "/#mainmenu" if the user clicks on logout -> ajax request -> if logout success go to "/#index". if logout failed remain on "/#mainmenu".

The issues that I am struggling with are:

1. A clean way to trigger transition to "/#mainmenu" after successful login (I currently use router.navigate("mainmenu", {trigger: true}); but read that should avoid using this approach, in derrick bailey's article https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/ )
2. A clean way to prevent the user to go back to the "/#index" when pressing Back button in the browser from "/#mainmenu" route. I will also would like to preserve the url hash to reflect the current view.
3. Prevent the user to go forward to "/#mainmenu" after successful logout.
4. Is that even possible to prevent url hash change when clicking browsers back/forward buttons?

When I say "clean" I refer to "what are the best practices?". I partially solved some issues by saving url hashes and restore the appropriate hash (by router.navigate(currentRoute, {replace: true}); ) but I feel that it's a hacky approach.

Any feedback is welcome and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is by applying an async `before` filter on the routes that require an auth status check before the actual callback route is executed.

For example: 
https://github.com/fantactuka/backbone-route-filter

The philosophy of avoiding `{trigger: true}` is based on the fact that when the router gets triggered with this flag, the entire initialization procedure for that route gets triggered. You will lose the benefit of having previously defined appstates because the app will have to re-initialize all content while this work had alrady been done before.

In practice, I think that it is useful to assess what your web app actually does. If losing appstate isn't an issue because the views you want to render are entirely new, then I don't see a problem with creating a client side redirect that re-inintializes your app.
If, on the other hand, your app has many views already rendered for which you want to maintain the same state as before, you can listen for an auth state event on each component that requires it, and make only those views re-render accordingly if they need to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about avoiding `{trigger:true}` and also for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think there's anything wrong with triggering routes, have been doing this without any issue for 2+ years. It all boils down to your requirements, read the article looks like a lot of work to me.
2. There are multiple ways to do this. First, you can disable [back/forward buttons](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/) using `window.history.forward()`. Second, my favourite, is to do the processing in [Router#execute](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute). A [sample](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute) might look like :

`execute: function(callback, args, name) {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      goToLogin();
      return false;    //the privileged route won't trigger
    }
    if (callback) callback.apply(this, args);
}`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I haven't thought about using history api directly. It seems like a good and reliable idea. I am going to try this approach. The "hacky" solution I had working looks very much similar to your above sample code. But from my experience pressing back/forward will change url hash and have to manually adjust it. I was hoping there is a better solution. Thanks for your feedback.